# How to edit the description to have my own custom text in it when a product is added?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, m2e-pro

I'm using my Magento store specifically with M2E Pro to list eBay products easily. My question is this...

How do I edit the description value form so that I can have my own custom text in it when a product is added? I need this because I have a template created in HTML for the eBay description pages and this is used within the description of the Magento column, but I don't want to have to paste the code in for over 400 products.

If I can have the text there all the time, then it would allow me to just add certain attributes to the description myself saving time.

I'm just not sure what file I should be looking for in the back-end of Magento.

Currently using version 1.5.

Comment: Any help with this would be amazing, have not found a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

If your question refers to editing the product attribute "description" of Magento, you can easily set a default value in the magento backend, via Menu Catalogue->Attributes->Manage Attributes. You can give a default value for each attribute here. But this only applies for new products you create.

If you want to give all existing products a default description value, you might use something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$default_description = 'your default description text';
foreach ($collection as $prod) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
        $product->setData('description', $default_description);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'description');
 }
```

Comment: Hi and tanks for reply. I basically want to put text into the description field, so that it will already be laces within the field on any product created or that is has previously been created.

Comment: Do you already have values in the description field of your existing products which need to be saved somehow? If not, you can just combine the two methods described above. Backend solution for future products, execution of code as a one-time solution for existing products.